# How to use 'logon' script for AD users loggin into MAC clients joined to AD domain

Tags: macos, mac, login

I have been trying to make automatic log-in for my shares on MAC client when i login a AD user into the MAC client.In short i am searching for alternative of the functionality called 'logon' GPO which AD gives while logging into Windows client joined to AD domain.

Is it possible for MAC client to automatically map the share while AD user login to MAC client ?

Thanks,
MAQ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you'll have to translate your Windows login script from whatever language it's in (.BAT, .VBS, .PS, etc.) to a bash shell script or AppleScript. The complexity of this is mostly dependent on the complexity of your Windows script. You'll have to translate items like "net use" to mount commands and find OSX equivalents for Windows commands. If you're doing it for yourself only, you can add it to your startup items in SysPref/Users. Or for larger audiences you may need to set it up as a LaunchAgent.

If you're looking for an enterprise solution, there are third party products from Centrify or Thursby that will make life easier too. GL

Comment: ,Thanks Sax,i was looking for enterprise solution as lot of MAC clients are included and adding the script in startup of each client is cumbersome activity.So ideally what you are saying is that Windows client joined to AD domain functions without these third party tool and MAC client joined to AD domain needs these third party tool for this functionality.Correct me i have understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @user370074 - that's pretty much the story. MS makes sure that Windows clients play well in AD. Apple is not as vested so there are gaps. A notable one is machine scripts and GPO. These need to be pushed with a 3rd party tool unless your inclined to write/support your own with something like RunDeck or Jenkins. FWIW, I've had great success with Casper Suite. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: excellent. it helped me a lot ! thank you :)

Comment: @user370074 - glad to hear it. Feel free to mark this as the answer. ;-) Cheers.